# how to get the user of chef-client process in a node

Tags: chef-infra

How to get the user of the chef-client process in a node.

```
the user who runs the chef-client agent.
```

I use ps command to get the user but not work well. any specific ruby method to get the user of chef-client process in a node.

Comment: You don't know as which user you launch chef-client ? it won't do anything weird unless you ask it to. The only change could be using sudo with knife commands. Please develop as I don't understand your question.

Comment: In almost all cases this is going to be root. What are you trying to do that you want this information?

Answer (score 1):

[Ohai](http://docs.getchef.com/ohai.html) populates an [automatic attribute](http://docs.getchef.com/chef_overview_attributes.html#automatic-ohai) for the user on each client run.

```rb
node['current_user']
```

Comment: Since Chef is designed to be run as root and [the expected behavior reflects that](https://github.com/chef/ohai/issues/451), it's now recommended to use `ENV['SUDO_USER']` for this.

Answer (score 0):

Few ohai plugins have been marked as optional recently. Make sure you enable them using client.rb file so that **node['current_user']** fetches you the current user.

Add below to client.rb and then use **node['current_user']**-

```
ohai.optional_plugins = [
  :Sessions,
  :Lspci,
  :Passwd
]
```